# How do I save pointers inside of pointer pointers?

Tags: c

I am receiving a segmentation fault on line 34 (through gdb, I've discovered that this is only occurring on the last iteration of the for loop when i=4). I am attempting to produce arrays such that:

```
pegRow[0] = [0]
pegRow[1] = [1, 1]
pegRow[2] = [1, 1, 1]
pegRow[3] = [1, 1, 1, 1]
pegRow[4] = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Since the error is occuring on the last iteration of the code, I thought the heart of the issue was that I was not allocating enough space inside of pegRow, but after allocating more than enough space the error still occurs. Any guidance would be much appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void initializeRows(int*** pegRow);

int main() {
    int **pegRow = malloc(5 * sizeof(int*));

    initializeRows(&pegRow);

    return 0;
}

void initializeRows(int*** pegRow) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        int* pegs = malloc((i + 1) * sizeof(int));
        int j;
        /* First peg is empty */
        if (i == 0) {
            pegs[0] = 0; 
        } else {
            /* The rest of pegs have 1 at entry */
            for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                pegs[j] = 1;
            }
        }
        *pegRow[i] = pegs;
    }
 }
```

Comment: It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (not a screenshot).

Comment: Post your code as code, not as a picture. You want to encourage people to run your code and help you, but nobody will bother to do that if you're asking them to waste their time transcribing images.

Comment: I think [] has precedence over * when dereferencing. Maybe try (*pegRow)[i]

Comment: I think `(*pegRow)[i] = pegs;` belongs inside the `for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)` loop.

Comment: @SteveSummit It was, but it didn't look like it because the code was poorly formatted. I fixed it

Comment: @Jimbology But did you take Layne Bernardo's suggestion?

Comment: Update, Layne Bernardo's suggestion worked! Is there a way I can pin that answer and close the thread?

Comment: @Jimbology You can post that as answer below - OK to write your own answer.

Comment: "Since the error is occuring on the last iteration of the code," is more like "the error is noticed on the last iteration of the code," (it may have occurred earlier.)

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that [] has precedence over * when dereferencing.
In other words:

```
*pegRow[i] = pegs;
```

should be changed to

```
(*pegRow)[i] = pegs;
```

Comment: Typo: You mean `(*pegRow)[i]`, not `*(pegRow)[i]` (the latter doesn't affect precedence). Or to avoid the precedence issue completely, just use indexing exclusively, making it `pegRow[0][i] = pegs;`

Comment: Please accept your answer ;). Glad you got it worked out.